# Personal access token in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using personal access token (PAT) in my powershell script but i am explicitly hard-coding it in my script as 
$pat = "some value"
and then im using it in same powershell script

anybody can help me how to avoid hard-coding of PAT in powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options 
1) You could keep the "PAT" in other file and call it in your powershell script
2) If you want it to be more secure  you can save your PAT in some file converting into a secure stirng using this [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-6) and while usage you could convert back again using [`ConvertFrom-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-6)
(note: To convert secure string into plain text use below code)

```
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecurePassword)<br>
$PlainText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

Comment: You could accept the answer if this worked or ask questions if further clarification required.

Comment: is there any other way of encrypting the PAT